# Efficient list culling

Tags: python

What would be the most efficient way (in terms of memory and cpu) to cull items from a big list in Python?
Is this a good way?

```
a = range(0,100000)
a[:] = [item for item in a if item > 10]
```

The numbers are just an example here. Could also be:

```
a = ["my", "very", "big", "list"]
a[:] = [item for item in a if item.startswith("b")]
```

Comment: your list won't always be ordered right?

Comment: Numpy will be good here.

Comment: do you mean `if item > 10`

Comment: @jamylak no just an example, can be anything

Comment: @ajon yes. changing..

Comment: yes, that's pretty efficient, but no need for `[:]`.

Comment: @andrew cooke - no, not necessarily, but I have other references to this list that I want to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want a list (and you want to replace your original list in place), you're probably not going to do a whole lot better than what you have with pure python.  However, this frequently isn't necessary.  Frequently, you just want an iterable object:

```
generator = (item for item in a if item > 10)
for item in generator:
    ...
```

This will be more memory efficient and the performance should be roughly the same.

Comment: What would be the performance gain? The items are in memory anyhow.

Comment: @RickyA -- when you do the slice assignment, the right hand side is evaluated first.  if you filter only a few items, then you're basically storing your list in memory twice (before you assign back into the original list).  This isn't usually a big deal, but you asked about memory efficiency ... In terms of performance, you'd need to `timeit`, but I'd expect the two approaches would be on par speed-wise.

Comment: ok, but the overhead would only be a new list with references to the values. Not a copy of the actual values since list comprehension does not copy the values. Right?

Comment: @RickyA -- With the list-comp you have, yes.  Of course, list-comps can create new values too:  `[3*x for x in a]`.  In that case you need to worry about the new objects you're creating.

Answer (score 1):

Python has generator functions built specifically for this purpose. See the docs [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Other than the use of `range` (the docs suggest using `xrange` which returns a generator), your implementation is perfectly fine.

The docs have the following example:

```
# Build and return a list
def firstn(n):
    num, nums = 0, []
    while num < n:
        nums.append(num)
        num += 1
    return nums

sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
```

That wastes *a lot* of space. So the docs suggest doing something like this instead:

```
# Using the generator pattern (an iterable)
class firstn(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.num, self.nums = 0, []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.num < self.n:
            cur, self.num = self.num, self.num+1
            return cur
        else:
            raise StopIteration()

sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))
```

Comment: Could you please give an example

Comment: `xrange` isn't a generator, it's a sequence object that evaluates lazily

Comment: It seems you are right, but I was confused because the link has this: "Both range and xrange represent a range of numbers, and have the same function signature, but range returns a list while xrange returns a generator (at least in concept; the implementation may differ)."

Comment: that is a wiki page so although it sounds correct, it's not actually true

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` or `generators` here

**Generator**

```
>>> data = [10, 20, 4, 4, 11, 13.4]
>>> custom_filter = (i for i in data if i > 10)
>>> [j for j in custom_filter]
[20, 11, 13.4]
>>>
```

**filter**

```
>>> data = [10, 20, 4, 4, 11, 13.4]
>>> custom_filter = filter(lambda x: x > 10, data)
>>> custom_filter
[20, 11, 13.4]
>>>
```